# is it possible to listen to codebase changes in rabbitmq consumer?

Tags: php, rabbitmq

I have a particular issue in rabbitmq using php-amqplib, where the consumer.php does not use the updated codebase and instead uses the old code.

Does rabbitmq has something similar to laravel listen command?
php artisan queue:listen
https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#running-the-queue-worker

If not can you suggest any alternatives for my usecase?

Answer (score 2):

You're muddling the responsibilities of different pieces of software here:

- RabbitMQ doesn't know or care that you're even running PHP
- php-amqplib doesn't care *what* PHP you're running, it just delivers messages to the callback you specify
- the Laravel command you linked is built *on top* of these technologies, not *instead of* them; it also explicitly says in the documentation you linked that it will *not* monitor for changes in your deployed code

A consumer script is generally a piece of PHP code containing an infinite loop; the general approach to running and restarting this is:

- Use something like [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) to restart it when it exits
- Include appropriate code to break out of the infinite loop, and thus make the script exit cleanly, when you deploy your code

Laravel's implementation of this is [the `queue:restart` command](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment), so you could look at how that's written for inspiration.